# Qt Android Extras Call Class

Tags: android, qt, java-native-interface, qtandroidextras

Say I have a Java class,

```
public static String helloWorld() {
    return "hello world!";
}
```

How, in Qt, do I get what this function returned? The example for notifications has the following:

```
QAndroidJniObject javaNotification = QAndroidJniObject::fromString(m_notification);
QAndroidJniObject::callStaticMethod<void>("org/qtproject/example/notification/NotificationClient",
                                   "notify",
                                   "(Ljava/lang/String;)V",
                                   javaNotification.object<jstring>());
```

Should by method descriptor be `()Ljava/lang/String;`? What should be in the chevrons after `callStaticMethod`?

Edit. Fixed and I don't know how. I didn't have the chevrons, and the descriptor was correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
QAndroidJniObject string = QAndroidJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod<jstring>("com/your/project/YourClass", "helloWorld");
```

Is equivalent to:

```
QAndroidJniObject string = QAndroidJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod("com/your/project/YourClass", "helloWorld", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
```

For trivial signatures, that is, signatures that takes no arguments and returns one of the know jni types, you can write the short version by supplying the template type.